# Access Wiki installation on Host from Virtual Server

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, localhost, hosts

Recently I set up a Dokuwiki installation on Ubuntu Server in VirtualBox. My host OS is Ubuntu 11.10. Till date I was using NAT configuration for my VirtualBox. Since today I decided to use Host-only networking as I did not want the wiki access to outside world. When I was using the NAT method I could access my wiki with this URL: http://localhost:8080/dokuwiki/doku.php. However after I switched to host-only way I am not able to do it.

After seeing instructions elsewhere I realized that using http://192.168.56.101/dokuwiki/doku.php helps but it did not help me. As instructed here, [How can I access Apache (on VirtualBox guest) from host?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52147/how-can-i-access-apache-on-virtualbox-guest-from-host) I tried adding following line to my hosts file

> 192.168.56.101  userver

with the idea of using http://userver/dokuwiki/doku.php to access my site. Even http://192.168.56.101/dokuwiki/doku.php did not work. So can anyone help me on how can I go about this?

Accessing with IP address in the URL would be OK, but I would like to know how I can set custom domain name for use.

**Update:** As suggested by R.K. I restarted both virtual and physical machines. Then I observed that before connecting to Internet the wiki is accessible with http://192.168.56.101/dokuwiki/doku.php or http://userver/dokuwiki/doku.php. Once I connect to the web using my USB dongle(I use `wvdial`) the wiki becomes inaccessible.

Comment: Have you checked the IP on your virtual machine? It may have changed.

Comment: I have checked IP using ipconfig on virtual machine. It shows `inet addr: 192.168.56.101` under `eth0`

Comment: After seeing instructions elsewhere> Got a link to the instructions? So you changed the port from 8080 to 80?

Comment: No, while using NAT I had to use port-forwarding and hence 8080 was used. After switching to host-only this step was not necessary.

Comment: Intriguing. Have you tried restarting the host or the virtual machine or both?

Comment: I tried after restarting my machine. I am able to access the wiki with either IP or even `userver` in the URL before connecting to internet. After I connect to web using my USB modem wiki becomes inaccessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to set the virtual machine's IP manually or activate VB's dhcp server. From the [documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly):

```
For host-only networking, like with internal networking, you may find the DHCP
server useful that is built into VirtualBox. This can be enabled to then 
manage the IP addresses in the host-only network since otherwise you would 
need to configure all IP addresses statically.
```

Comment: I have enabled this.