# Which installer will install ubuntu on an AMD E450 APU with Radeon 2 GB RAM on samsung machine

Tags: ati, samsung, oracle

I want to install Ubuntu to install Oracle database for learning purpose.  I have Samsung machine with AMD E450 APU with Radeon 2 GB Ram.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ubuntu installer :)

For your purposes I would go with Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit version. Newer versions are awesome but if your new to Ubuntu and might run into problems, then there will be more information on 12.04 than 12.10 or 13.04 versions. 12.04 is LTS (Long Term Support) release and 64-bit version of it is most likely variant to be run on servers (I suppose).

If you want to use it mainly for learning, then also consider running it in Virtualbox. Its easier to restart your project and reinstall Ubuntu if you have messed something up and you can interact with the Virtualbox guest (Ubuntu used for learning) from your host (whatever OS you are using on your PC). To give you some ideas look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52147/how-can-i-access-apache-on-virtualbox-guest-from-host). That one is about connecting to Apache server on the guest but from networking perspective it is the same.