# Can't find my internal IP Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, networking, virtualbox, apache2

I've been trying to access Apache from my host so I could access it from firefox etc. 
I've been following the guide [How can I access Apache (on VirtualBox guest) from host?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52147/how-can-i-access-apache-on-virtualbox-guest-from-host) from this page but when I write

`ifconfig | grep addr` or just `ifconfig`, the only ip address I can see is the localhost 127.0.0.1.

I'm using host-adapter only(Virtual machine) and I'm currently sitting on my schools Wifi which everyone is using, and several people from my class is having no problems at all showing the internal ip address.

Anyone that could give me any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to bridge adapter in the VirtualBox settings for your machine. If you choose bridge adapter for the machine it gets it's own local ip address from the dhcp. That way you can communicate with the machine from the host computer or any other computer on the LAN.

Comment: Sure, i can try that.. Do i need to change anything like MAC-address etc or can i just change to Bridge-adapter?

Comment: Just change to the bridge adapter, it should work directly. However if you have changed network settings on your machine like static ip address and such, you need to 'reset' to standard settings. So you get network settings from the dhcp instead.

Comment: Can't get it working, only time it shows an IP-address is when Cable connected is checked. 
I have even tried diffrent networks but doesn't work when its not checked anyway.